# Making toggle MenuItem a sliding (ON/OFF) button with cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, togglebutton

While using cocos2d-x got stuck with a problem. A toggle menu is made for sounds and music on-off switch. I want to make them draggable like in apple native ui they are. searched the net and even in the forum and documentation.

Comment: You mean you want an (on|off) sliding button, like many items in the Settings app use? If you want to animate the button change you'd have to custom code it, it can't be done with CCMenuItem (unless you costumize it accordingly).

Comment: yes that is what i want to do. But i also want to use it as toggle menu button... Like in seetings option of any iOS device

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is CCControlSwitch.

[image: switch control]

```
CCSprite *onSprite = CCSprite::create("ui/switch-on.png");
CCSprite *offSprite = CCSprite::create("ui/switch-off.png");
CCSprite *thumbSprite = CCSprite::create("ui/switch-thumb.png");
CCSprite *maskSprite = CCSprite::create("ui/switch-mask.png");

CCControlSwitch *control = CCControlSwitch::create(maskSprite, onSprite, offSprite, thumbSprite, nullptr, nullptr);
control->setOn(status);
control->needsLayout();
control->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(DebugLayer::toggleShowStats),, CCControlEventValueChanged);
addChild(control);
```

There's an example in samples/Cpp/TestCpp/Classes/ExtensionsTest/ControlExtensionTest within your cocos2dx distro.

Hope it helps,
Laurent